# Connecting SQL 2008 from SQL 2005 Enterprise Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is It Possible to connect SQL Server 2008 from SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Manager?

I am getting below mentioned error while connecting An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

Comment: How? Could you please Explain. I am getting below mentioned error while connecting

An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1326&LinkId=20476

Comment: there problem in your setting if you use network the ask your administrator to check the rights given to your login user. and Default setting is default connected to what ever you define in the Default setting when you install the sql.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable remote connections?

Under SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration --> Client Protocols, you need to enable TCP/IP (I assume that's what you are using).